# The application was unable to start (0xc0150002) with libcurl C++ Windows 7 VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, libcurl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0150002)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537429/the-application-failed-to-initialize-properly-0xc0150002)

Hi Everyone so i followed the guide below to get my Visual Studio 2010 to work with libcurl & Windows 7.

[Link 1](http://theetrain.ca/tech/installing-curl-using-visual-studio-2010-beginners-guide/)
[Link 2](http://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/using-libcurl-with-visual-c-2010/)

However i am facing the above stated error:

```
The application was unable to start (0xc0150002)
```

I followed steps carefully:

A: Setup

```
Create Empty Project & add in source file provided by libcurl (simple.c)
```

B: Link your libraries

```
You may try pressing F7, but it won’t work. You need to set up your
linker and what-not. On the toolbar, go to Project>Properties

Go to Configuration Properties>VC++ Directories>Include Directories
and go to <Edit> (click on the drop-down arrow to the right)

Create a new line and browse for your cURL directory. Browse for
cURL>include>curl and then click “OK”

Next, create a new line for Library Directories and navigate for
cURL>lib>Debug and then click “OK”

Lastly, under Configuration Properties>Linker>Input, edit the
Additional Dependencies and create a new line

Browse for cURL>lib>Debug>curllib.lib and paste its source link into
your Additional Dependencies dialogue box
```

C: Try the sample code

```
During run-time, however, there will be errors due to missing DLL files. 
This can be easily fixed by copying and pasting curllib.dll, libeay32.dll, openldap.dll,
and ssleay32.dll from the cURL directory and into your project folder.
```

So... after following the instructions i get that error. any idea? :)
I have seen similar questions, but there  is no clearly stated answers.

**Debug Output:**

```
'dummy.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\lyon\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\dummy\Release\dummy.exe', Symbols loaded.
'dummy.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'dummy.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'dummy.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'dummy.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\lyon\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\dummy\dummy\curllib.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
The program '[3740] dummy.exe: Native' has exited with code -1072365566 (0xc0150002).
```

Comment: It is a very common question, just type "0xc0150002" in the Search box at the upper right of this page.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dependency Walker Did the trick.

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

It helped me pinpoint the exact location of my error which was the libcurl.dll

I did a little googling and found out that...

**64-bit solution**

All i had to do is copy libcurl.dll into C:/Windows/SYSWOW64
Note: You have to use the libcurl.dll that you downloaded from the package you downloaded or else you will get errors as the version is different